# Apple Push Notification Service with Python

Tags: python, ssl, apple-push-notifications

everyone,

I met a problem about APNs when I used the code below.
I have found many kinds of source code to achieve this service

```
import socket, ssl, json, struct import binascii

deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX' 

thePayLoad = {
     'aps': {
          'alert':'Hello world',
          'sound':'default',
          'badge':42,
          },
     'test_data': { 'foo': 'bar' },
     }

theCertfile = 'iphone_ck.pem'  

theHost = ( 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195 )

data = json.dumps( thePayLoad )

deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(' ','') 

byteToken = binascii.unhexlify(deviceToken)

theFormat = '!BH32sH%ds' % len(data) theNotification = struct.pack( theFormat, 0, 32, 

byteToken, len(data), data )

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket( socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ), certfile = theCertfile ) 

ssl_sock.connect( theHost )

ssl_sock.write( theNotification )

ssl_sock.close()
```

After I executed the code, and I got an error below.
Everytime when I tried to use PyAPNs on GitHub or APNWrapper on Google
I found that the error at last.
So, I decided to implement by myself.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testAPN.py", line 38, in <module>
    ssl_sock.connect( theHost )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 309, in connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 293, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 
alert handshake failure
```

Could anyone help me to figure out this error or give me some possible directions to 
finish this function?

Comment: must be configuration issue, PyAPNS works fine for me.

Comment: I have solved this problem, because I had made a mistake to earn my pem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to use APNSWrapper module for this task.

http://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/

It is simple and common use.

Answer (score 0):

Another library that you could use is

https://bitbucket.org/catwashere/pycat-apns

You don't have to fight with the message structure or with the connection